# String extract str_extract with R script

Tags: r, string, extract, text-extraction, rscript

I have files which have this structure: `xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_class0.png` and `xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_class1.png`. I want to select only class0 or class1 images.

I did:

```
 ## List images in path
images_names <- list.files("/img/train",pattern="\\.png$",recursive = TRUE)
if(labelsExist){
    ## Select only class0 or class1 images
    classLb <- str_extract(images_names, "^(class0|class1)")
    # Set class0 == 0 and class1 == 1
    key <- c("class0" = 0, "class1" = 1)
    y <- key[classLb]
  }
```

When I perform, `head(classLb)`, I have only `NA` in output. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sub` and a regex pattern `.*([a-z]+).png`. This claims that to delete everything until a `_` followed a word then `.png`

```
sub('.*_([a-z]+).png', '\\1', image_names)
```